# Regex to get 2 specific words on a line

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, notepad++

I am trying to get 2 or more 3 words using regex. but I am having a hard time to get only the words and not the whole line.

below is the text.

> 3255 2010-02-14 13:17:14 WARN HA Disabling alerts for the next 600 seconds. Policy is still enforced
>
> 3256 2010-02-14 13:18:17 WARN UDM Adaptive Filter configuration disabled filter "13379: HTTP: Cool PDF Image Stream Length Buffer Overflow Vulnerability" [00000002-0002-0002-0002-000000013379]

regex I use is

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*disabled filter.*$  -> this work but will get the whole line.
```

I am trying to get only the date and the disabled filter from text,

ex. 2016-02-14 13:18:17 filter "13379: HTTP: Cool PDF Image Stream Length Buffer Overflow Vulnerability"

I tried using pipe but it will also get another date on a different line

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|disabled filter|"[0-9]{5}.+"
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What language are you using? Python, perl, java etc??

Comment: I use find/search with regex on notepad++ and sublime text

Comment: Ok, Please see below in my post. I have posted couple of regex flavors including Notepad++

Comment: I tried the regex you posted, it match the filter number until " . Is it possible to get date and timing too without including the words in between those two.

Comment: Indeed it's possible. But as you know Notepad++ and Sublime both doesn't support showing groups.

Comment: ah okay.. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Here is regex if you want to search for both
`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?:.*)(?<=disabled filter ")([^"]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since language is missing, here are few solutions.

> Python

```
match = re.search('(?<=disabled filter ")[^"]+', subject, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    result = match.group()
```

> Java

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=disabled filter \")[^\"]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

> Notepad ++ and Sublime Text

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?:.*)(?<=disabled filter ")([^"]+)
```

Group(1) will have `date` and Group(2) contains `filter`